# Spring Mvc Dynamic RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My problem is dynamic url on controller.I have category tree.My category has n number subcategories.

My url : www.xyz.com/category/mainCategory/subCategory/subCategory/subCategory/subCategory

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/category/**")
public class CategoryController {

    ????     
    public void init()

}
```

How do I defined dynamic requestmapping?.

Comment: Like that, you will have to parse the request string yourself.

Comment: @Affe I looking best practices.How solved other people this case.
My solutions code : 
String url = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);

Comment: If yu think nickdos solution solves your problem then you can give a check (right mark option) for further people..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could also try something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/category/{path}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void categoryTest(@PathVariable("path") String path, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    String remainingPaths = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    logger.debug("path = " + path + "/" + remainingPaths);
}
```

Comment: Is this how to get that value of `/**` part?

Comment: From memory, the part of the path matched by `/**` is captured in the variable `remainingPaths` in the code above (without leading `/`). This was posted 9 years ago, so this solution might not work with more recent versions of Spring.